# How to make iMacro find only the exact string in a TXT attribute

Tags: macros, scripting, imacros, web-scripting

I am putting together an iMacro for firefox, and I am having trouble making iMacro find only the exact strong in the TXT attribute. In this iMacro, I am looking for a `<span>` with the string `follow`.

Here is the piece of the script:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:follow
```

**Problem**: There are `<span>` elements with the string `following` that the iMacro is picking up.

**Question**: How can I write the macro so that it will only find the `<span>` with the exact string `follow`?

---

**Edit:** Added HTML (Note: I need the iMacro to click the button)

Here is the page: http://ink361.com/app/users/ig-183814919/followers

**Follow:**

```
<button id="followButton" class="followButton normalbutton " data-picture="http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_397057078_75sq_1369928076.jpg" data-username="bealilyy" data-userid="ig-397057078">
    <span class="followstatus"></span>
    <div class="text">
       <span class="following">                        <----hidden
          <span class="onhover">Unfollow</span>        <----hidden
          <span class="normal">Following</span>        <----hidden
       </span>                                         <----hidden
       <span class="notfollowing"> Follow </span>
    </div>
</button>
```

**Following:**

```
<button id="followButton" class="followButton normalbutton following" data-picture="http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_183814919_75sq_1361757071.jpg" data-username="jcrew" data-userid="ig-183814919">
    <span class="followstatus follows"></span>
    <div class="text">
       <span class="following">
          <span class="onhover">Unfollow</span>   <----hidden
          <span class="normal">Following</span>
       </span>
       <span class="notfollowing"> Follow </span> <----hidden
    </div>
 </button>
```

---

EDIT 2: Another issue is that `<span class="normal">Following</span>` is also in the "follow" HTML text div but is just hidden with `display:none` so it picks those up too.

Comment: your code is correct - it should click on push only, if it clicks on something different, then tag defined differently on the page and you need to provide page code snippet or link to page to get the answer.

Comment: @Bestmacros Just added a code snippet of the push and pushed ``<button>`` elements. The only stipulation is that the macro has to actually click the button instead of just find the right element. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=class:push
```

Comment: I don't think that would work, because the attribute's class isn't push, it's "normal".

Comment: Just tried that, and the issue is that ``<span class="normal">Pushed</span>`` is also in the ``text`` div but is just hidden with ``display:none`` so it picks those up too.

Comment: Just started a bounty if you want to check out the edits I made and see if there is a possible solution.

Comment: according to provided page html my code should work, if it does not work, when something is much more different on the website itself and without seeing it is impossible to provide solution